# Improving Pandas read_csv speed in chunksize mode

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a 10Gb file by using chunksize pd read_csv, but I notice that the speed of read_csv just goes slower and slower. Furthermore, after some iterations, i would get a warning message about "my disk is almost full". It feels like pd doesn't delete the old memory when load the new chunk of data. it would be great if I can somehow tell python that after loading the chuncksize data frame and write out the output, erase memory for this chunk and replace it with the new chunks

I've changed the chunksize from 10000 to 3000, and the problem of read_csv() getting slower and slower still exists. After I read the chunk of file, I do some operations on it (deleting some rows based on some criterions) and write the new output to a csv file.

```
for i in range(0, number_lines, chucksize):
    read_all_cat=pd.read_csv(all_cat_file_name, error_bad_lines=False, sep='\\t', header=None, nrows=chucksize, skiprows=i, engine='python')
```

Comment: You should use the normal chunking operations available with `pd.read_csv` which gives you basically a generator that you can exhaust by running through all of the chunks.

Comment: is nrow=chucksize much less efficient than chunksize=chucksize

Comment: I mean you simply need to specify `chunksize` and then pandas will handle the iteration: See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk). Create the reader with `reader = pd.read_csv('file_name', chunksize=3000)`, then do something like `for chunk in reader: ...`

Answer (score 0):

You may use garbage collector at the end of for loop.

```
import gc

for i in range(0, number_lines, chucksize):
    read_all_cat=pd.read_csv(file, **kwargs)
    # ...
    # other operations
    # ...

    del read_all_cat, other_variables
    gc.collect()
```

Or you can use `pd.read_csv(**options)` **chunksize** option it may be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. The gc is super helpful. I am also using it for other codes for memory cleanup too